# Array and loops

Tags: c

I have an array contain 100 elements. Can anyone help me to figure out how to write loops that perform this:

```
data[0] = 1/(2*3*4)
data[1] = 1/(4*5*6)
data[2] = 1/(6*7*8)
...
data[99] = 1/(200*201*202)


data[0]-data[1]+data[2]-data[3]+data[4]-data[5]+...+data[98]-data[99]
```

I just can't understand how to start. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Look at functions... then try something like data[i]=operation(j) where operation is a function that does return 1 / ( (j)*(j+1)*(j+2) ), then increment j and i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
double c=0;
for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
 c=i*2+2;
 data[i]=1/(c*(c+1)*(c+2));
}
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i+=2)
{
  op+= data[i] - data[i+1];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this piece! Particular this one made my program run correctly!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions how to start, if you really want them and want to manage this by your own:

1. Generalize your algorithm:

   1. Find a function `f(x)` such that `data[i] = f(i)`
   2. Just write the algorithm in your native language.
2. Then learn basic operators of C language, including *loop* construct.
3. Write your "native language algorithm" in C language.

Answer (score 0):

Just in one loop:

```
int total = 0;
for(size_t i=0; i<100; ++i){
  int temp = (i+1)*2;
  data[i] = 1/(temp*(temp+1)*(temp+2));
  total = total + (i%2==0?data[i]:-data[i]);
}
```

Comment: Nice one! But you need parenthesis around your ternery `?` expression due to operator precedence. Right now it will be interpreted as: `total = (total + i%2==0)?data[i]:-data[i]`. So add parenthesis like this: `total = total + (i%2==0?data[i]:-data[i]);`

Comment: @KlasLindbäck That's right - thank you. I edited it accordingly.